# Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: linux, shorewall

Hey friends i am getting the following error when i am trying to purge shorewall

```
root@aptosid:/etc# apt-get purge shorewall 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
The following packages will be REMOVED: 
  shorewall* 
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 3 not upgraded. 
1 not fully installed or removed. 
After this operation, 1,843 kB disk space will be freed. 
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
(Reading database ... 212702 files and directories currently installed.) 
Removing shorewall ... 
: not found/shorewall: 25: /etc/default/shorewall: :q 
Stopping "Shorewall firewall": not done (check /var/log/shorewall-init.log). 
invoke-rc.d: initscript shorewall, action "stop" failed. 
dpkg: error processing shorewall (--purge): 
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1 
configured to not write apport reports 
                                      Errors were encountered while processing: 
 shorewall 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) 
root@aptosid:/etc#
```

please help me out ...........?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the install is messed up and some of the configuration files are missing.  You might be able to get it to continue if you do

```
touch /etc/default/shorewall
```

but more likely you'll need to reinstall the package to get the missing configuration back, then purge it.  To reinstall it you'll need to do

```
apt-get install --reinstall shorewall
```